# Why does the relation $-(a+b)^{2} ≠ (-a-b)^{2}$ not hold?

Tags: calculus, inequality

I have a question about a remarkable identity.
Why does:

$$-(a+b)^{2} ≠ (-a-b)^{2}$$

It should be equal if i distributed the minus sign to the parenthesis, no ?

I am sorry but I don't understand that.

Can I have some help?

Comment: Substitute $a=b=1$.

Comment: Your LHS is always negative while your RHS is always positive(non trivial cases).

Comment: Does not hold generally, say $a =- b$?

Comment: If you distribute the minus sign you get $(-a-b)^2=(-(a+b))^2 = (-1)^2(a+b)^2 = 1\cdot(a+b)^2=(a+b)^2$, since the square of a negative number is positive.

Comment: `-(a+b)^2=-[a^2+b^2+2ab]=-a^2-b^2-2ab` which is extremely different from `(-a-b)^2=(-a)^2+(-b)^2+2ab=a^2+b^2+2ab`

Comment: Is $-(1)^2$ equal to $(-1)^2$ ? How exactly do you *“distribute the minus sign to the parenthesis”* ?

Comment: When a statement specifies two things are *not equal*, we can't call that statement an identity.  Perhaps you meant "non-identity"?  In any case equality would imply that $a+b=0$ in that statement.

Answer (score 2):

In general, you cannot distribute a term into the parenthesis, unless it has the same exponent. That is,

$$a(b+c)^x\neq (ab+ac)^x.$$

So, as a slightly more concrete example,

$$4(a+b)^2\neq (4a+4b)^2.$$ However, we can change the $4$ in a way that *does* let us distribute. Specifically, $4=2^2$, so

$$4(a+b)^2= 2^2(a+b)^2=(2a+2b)^2.$$

Now, specifically for your question, we have

$$-(a+b)^2=(-1)^1(a+b)^2$$

Since these do not have the same exponent, we cannot distribute.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, let us prove that $0x = 0$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
0x = (0 + 0)x = 0x + 0x & \Rightarrow 0x + (-0x) = 0x + (0x + (-0)x)\\\\
& \Rightarrow 0 = 0x + 0\\\\
& \Rightarrow 0 = 0x
\end{align*}

Once we have proven such result, it is useful to demonstrate that $-x = (-1)x$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$:
\begin{align*}
(-1)x + x & = (-1)x + 1x\\\\
& = ((-1) + 1)x\\\\
& = 0x = 0
\end{align*}

Since the opposite is unique, we may infer that $(-1)x = -x$.

Finally, it remains to prove that $(-1)(-1) = 1$. Indeed, this is the case:
\begin{align*}
(-1)(-1) - 1 & = (-1)(-1) + (-1)\\\\
& = (-1)(-1) + 1(-1)\\\\
& = ((-1) + 1)(-1)\\\\
& = 0(-1)\\\\
& = 0
\end{align*}
whence the proposed claim is true.

Gathering all these results, let $\{a,b\}\subset\mathbb{R}$. Thus we conclude that
\begin{align*}
(-a - b)^{2} & = ((-1)a + (-1)b)^{2}\\\\
& = [(-1)(a + b)]^{2}\\\\
& = (-1)^{2}(a + b)^{2}\\\\
& = 1(a + b)^{2}\\\\
& = (a + b)^{2}
\end{align*}

which (in general) is different from $-(a+b)^{2}$, and we are done.

Hopefully this helps !

Comment: Exactly useful answer.